# How to easily change String formatted like "20 0F 01" into hex values in Java?

Tags: java, hex

I've found method **toHexString()** but it converts string into hex, while the **value is already converted (like "20 0F 01 etc.")**. **What's the best way to get hex values from this String** for later purposes (ex. adding, sending some of them to output device)?

Comment: You want to parse hex string into `int`? If so `Integer` have method `parseInt` with two parameters, last one is radix, pass 16 there.

Comment: Actually it would be better to be able to have it in byte array like: byte[] {0x20, 0x20, 0x0F, 0xFF}

Comment: Then split string by `yourString.split(" ")` before parsing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Integer.parseInt(String val, int radix)
```

Example
 Integer.parseInt("-FF", 16) returns -255

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` to break the string up into individual bytes, and `Integer.parseInt(s, 16)` to convert the string representation into an integer.

Something like this should work:

```
List<Integer> parseHex(String hex) {
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String s : hex.split("\\s+")) {
          a.add(Integer.parseInt(s, 16));
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention preferring a byte array, you can use a ByteBuffer to accumulate byte values:

```
String text = "20 0F 01";

ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((text.length() + 1) / 3);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
while (scanner.hasNextInt(16)) {
    buffer.put((byte) scanner.nextInt(16));
}

byte[] bytes = buffer.array();
```

We use hasNextInt and nextInt, rather than hasNextByte and nextByte, because Java’s numeric types are signed, and values above `7f` are not representable as signed bytes.